# How can I send a cookie from a Web.Api controller method

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web.Api service which has a method that accepts a custom class and returns another custom class:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public CustomResponse Post([FromBody]CustomRequest request)
    {
        // process request
        ...
        // create response
        CustomResponse resp = new CustomResponse() { ... };
        return resp;
    }
}
```

Now I want to also send a cookie back as part of the Http response. How can I do that?

Answer (score 36):

I managed to do this by combining information from a few different locations. First, in order to easily be able to send cookies in the response, the Web.Api controller should return an instance of the `System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage` class ([link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-cookies)):

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]CustomRequest request)
    {
        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage();
        ...

        //create and set cookie in response
        var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("customCookie", "cookieVal");
        cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
        cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
        cookie.Path = "/";
        resp.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });

        return resp;
    }
}
```

But then how do I make sure that I can easily ALSO send back the `CustomResponse`?

The trick is in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14877775/1429080) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14877524/1429080). Use the `Request.CreateResponse<T>` method on the request object. The whole deal then becomes:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]CustomRequest request)
    {
        // process request
        ...

        var resp = Request.CreateResponse<CustomResponse>(
            HttpStatusCode.OK,
            new CustomResponse() { ... }
        );

        //create and set cookie in response
        var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("customCookie", "cookieVal");
        cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
        cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
        cookie.Path = "/";
        resp.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });

        return resp;
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks right. If you're doing this in a lot of action methods, you could put it into an action filter.

Comment: I was all "wow this great this web api stuff" until I saw this. What a shame you can't just add a cookie without having to return a HttpResponseMessage. I thought the idea was to make Web API easier than WCF. I'm afraid I don't see that. How can an action filter help here without adding yet more complexity to such a simple requirement. Don't get it.

Comment: Sorry if I may ask, I'm a bit confused. Do I need to grab the response cookie in the client and set it, or the browser that gets the set-cookie response header should automatically do this ?

Comment: @FrancisDucharme If your client is a browser (maybe you're doing Ajax to fetch data) then the browser should handle the cookie for you. If your client is a Windows program (or similar) then you _may_ have to code some cookie handling yourself. I suggest you post a new question with the details of your specific situation...

Answer (score 4):

With recent versions of Web API, `async`, and `IHttpActionResult`, we can now simply do this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyMethod(... myParameters ...)
{
    ...
    var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("myCookie", "myValue");
    ...

    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage();
    resp.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    resp.Headers.AddCookies(new[] { cookie });
    return ResponseMessage(resp);
}
```